# Does having two threads monitoring the OutputStream and InputStream of a socket affect each other?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

So I have a client-server interface made in Java. I want to accept messages from multiple clients which functions beautifully. I then want to broadcast the received messages from those clients to all the other connected clients, which does not function as expected.

I try to broadcast the received message through a for loop in the Server class:

```
private void broadcastMessage(String message) {

        for (int i = 0, j = clients.size(); i <= j; i++) {
            PrintWriter out = null;
            Socket socket = clients.get(i);
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // WHERE YOU ISSUE THE COMMANDS
            out.println(message);
            Log.d("SERVER Loop", "Broadcasting messages...");
            out.close();
        }
        Log.d("SERVER", "Message Brodcasted");
    }
```

This I then try to receive through a listener in the Client class :

```
    public class ClientThreadListener implements Runnable {

    protected Socket serverSocket = null;
    protected String mMsgFromServer;

    public ClientThreadListener(Socket serverSocket) {
        this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    serverSocket.getInputStream()));

            while ((mMsgFromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("MESSAGE FROM SERVER: ", mMsgFromServer);
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        msgFromOtherClients.append('\n'
                                + "Message From Server: " + mMsgFromServer);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientListener", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors or force closes though. Forgive me I know it is very messy but please bear with me and please focus on the issue at hand instead :D

Here is the full code for the Server class

```
public class Server extends Activity {

private TextView serverStatus;

// DEFAULT IP
public static String SERVERIP = "10.0.2.15";

// DESIGNATE A PORT
public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

private String mMsgFromClient;

private MultiThreadedServer server;

private ArrayList<Socket> clients = new ArrayList<Socket>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.server);
    serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status);

    // SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();

    server = new MultiThreadedServer(8080);
    new Thread(server).start();

}

public class MultiThreadedServer implements Runnable {

    protected int serverPort = 8080;
    protected ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    protected boolean isStopped = false;
    protected Thread runningThread = null;

    public MultiThreadedServer(int port) {
        this.serverPort = port;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
        }
        openServerSocket();
        while (!isStopped()) {
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {
                clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
                clients.add(clientSocket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (isStopped()) {
                    Log.d("SERVER TEXT", "Server Stopped.");
                    return;
                }
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Error accepting client connection", e);
            }
            new Thread(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket, this)).start();

        }
        Log.d("SERVER TEXT", "Server Stopped.");
    }

    private synchronized boolean isStopped() {
        return this.isStopped;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        this.isStopped = true;
        try {
            this.serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
        }
    }

    private void openServerSocket() {
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port 8080", e);
        }
    }

    private void broadcastMessage(String message) {

        for (int i = 0, j = clients.size(); i <= j; i++) {
            PrintWriter out = null;
            Socket socket = clients.get(i);
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // WHERE YOU ISSUE THE COMMANDS
            out.println(message);
            Log.d("SERVER Loop", "Broadcasting messages...");
            out.close();
        }
        Log.d("SERVER", "Message Brodcasted");
    }

}

public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable {

    protected Socket clientSocket = null;
    protected String mMsgFromClient = null;

    private UUID id;

    public WorkerRunnable(Socket clientSocket, MultiThreadedServer server) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        id = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            while ((mMsgFromClient = in.readLine()) != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.append('\n'
                                + "Message From Client ID " + getID()
                                + ": " + mMsgFromClient);
                    }
                });
            }
            Log.d("SERVERTEXT", "Proceed to broadcast");
            server.broadcastMessage(mMsgFromClient);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    serverStatus
                            .append('\n'
                                    + "Message From Client ID "
                                    + getID()
                                    + ": "
                                    + "Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private String getID() {
        return id.toString();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the full code for the Client class

```
public class Client extends Activity {

private EditText serverIp;
private EditText chatMsg;
private Button connectPhones;
private Button sendMsg;
private TextView msgFromOtherClients;

private String serverIpAddress = "";

private boolean connected = false;
private boolean willSendMsg = false;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.client);

    serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
    connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);
    connectPhones.setOnClickListener(connectListener);

    chatMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chat_msg);
    sendMsg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_msg);
    sendMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            willSendMsg = true;
        }
    });

    msgFromOtherClients = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg_from_other_clients);
}

private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!connected) {
            serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
            if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                cThread.start();
            }
        }
    }
};

public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);

            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");

            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, Server.SERVERPORT);
            connected = true;

            Thread listener = new Thread(new ClientThreadListener(socket)));
            listener.start();

            while (connected) {
                if (willSendMsg) {
                    willSendMsg = false;
                    try {
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                                new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                        socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                        // WHERE YOU ISSUE THE COMMANDS
                        out.println(chatMsg.getText().toString());
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            socket.close();
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}

public class ClientThreadListener implements Runnable {

    protected Socket serverSocket = null;
    protected String mMsgFromServer;

    public ClientThreadListener(Socket serverSocket) {
        this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    serverSocket.getInputStream()));

            while ((mMsgFromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("MESSAGE FROM SERVER: ", mMsgFromServer);
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        msgFromOtherClients.append('\n'
                                + "Message From Server: " + mMsgFromServer);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientListener", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

So as you can see I have two threads listenin in to the server socket. I don't seem to know what happens though why I can't broadcast the message or why I can't receive it.

Comment: Have you tried to do a pool of "OpenStreams/InputStreams" in stead of a pool of "clients", the way I see it, seems like when fetching the clients after getting the "OutputStream" to wrap it PrintWritter, the print writter might be closing the stream, and it might work the first time but after that the client's connection might get lost, why dont you try to create a pool of outputstreams, and just write/flush the data in stead of closing it all the time...

Comment: I kind of don't understand. But I can send multiple messages from the clients to the server, is that what you were hinting at?

Answer (score 1):

Closing the input or output stream of a socket, or the socket, closes the other stream(s) and the socket. Remove `out.close().`

TCP sockets are full duplex so there is nothing intrinsically wrong with what you're doing, although I would hardly describe writing to a socket as 'monitoring' it.

Comment: Thanks for that input! I'll try this and I'll let you know what happened

Comment: I removed the `out.close` and also the `socket.close` from the client class but it still does not seem to receive the messages.